# CSS selector not working with Nokogiri?

Tags: css, ruby, scripting, web-scraping, nokogiri

I was trying to scrape some information from http://www.vrbo.com/354035#calendar, but with Nokogiri and CSS selectors I am not able to fetch the value that I want.

In the page source, I am seeing `<div class="calmonth">` which comes after `<h2>Calendar</h2>` in the HTML. But when I use Nokogiri and try:

```
page = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://www.vrbo.com/354035#calendar"))

calendar = page.css("div.calmonth")
```

`calendar` is empty which shouldn't be.

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: @ArupRakshit I edited the question, please take a look now.

Comment: There is no `<div class="calmonth">` in returned HTML, in fact there is nothing in the HTML with a `calmonth` class. Perhaps it is being added by some JavaScript.

Comment: @ArupRakshit Sent mail

Comment: @muistooshort any other method to extract it?

Comment: Try looking at the raw HTML rather than the HTML you see in the browser, if you're lucky you'll find what you want and be able to figure out the right selector.

Comment: Sure @muistooshort thank you.. I think I should use Watir in this case.

Comment: When you ask a question about parsing, please include a summarized version of the HTML that demonstrates the problem, plus an example of what you want to capture, or what your result should be.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [watir](http://watir.com/) insteed of Nokogiri. It will help you do all the js tricks and you will find the `<div class="calmonth">` in the resulting HTML page.